# Get Wordpress data by Post ID

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

The following code successfully gets all the Woocommerce products of the `category` "tools", from my Wordpress website.

```
<?php
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'product',
'posts_per_page' => 100,
'product_cat' => 'tools'
);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);

while ($loop->have_posts()):
$loop->the_post();
global $product;
echo '<br /><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail() . ' ' . the_title() . ' ' . the_content() . ' ' . get_post_meta(get_the_ID() , '_regular_price', true) . ' ' . get_post_meta(get_the_ID() , '_sale_price', true) . '</a>';
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

This works fine and returns all the products in the `category` "tools".

However I am now trying to get a product by its `post id`. So instead of by `category` by `id`. And I want to get all the data on the product as above , ie, its title, content, image, sale price and regular price.

I tried the code below but it didn't work.

```
<?php
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'product',
'posts_per_page' => 100,
'ID' => '254'
);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);

while ($loop->have_posts()):
$loop->the_post();
global $product;
echo '<br /><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail() . ' ' . the_title() . ' ' . the_content() . ' ' . get_post_meta(get_the_ID() , '_regular_price', true) . ' ' . get_post_meta(get_the_ID() , '_sale_price', true) . '</a>';
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

How do I get all the information on a product as I did in the first piece of code (By category), but by its `ID` instead?

So for example, in the above code, I was attempting to get the data on the product with the post id of 254. So the information on that one product.

I assumed I would look for the `ID` instead of `product_cat` in the `$args` array.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (unless I read something wrong) and read comments:

```
<?
$args = array(
// 'post_type' => 'post', // what I used to test
'post_type' => 'product', // what you need
'posts_per_page' => 100,
//'ID' => '254' // this would limit the results to ID 254 ONLY - so this is bad
);
// Generates the result set
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
//echo "<pre>\r\n"; // makes output easy to read

// uncomment next line to see what else is available
// var_dump($loop->posts);

// Don't actually need to be in the loop to use the query result
foreach ($loop->posts as $p){
    echo 'post_title :'.$p->post_title."<br />\r\n";
    echo 'post_name :'.$p->post_name."<br />\r\n";
    echo 'post_content :'.$p->post_content."<br />\r\n";
    echo 'ID :'.$p->ID."<br />\r\n";
}
```

Worked on my Local WP sandbox using type 'posts'. I believe Woo is using a custom post type for products (just a post/page with a new name - super handy feature in WP).

Good luck.

Comment: Actually used `'p'=>254` and it worked as suggested in the comment above by @Ohgodwhy and by following your example

Comment: Cool. Thx for green check mark. There are sooo many ways to do what you want, but this is one that is easier and pretty straight forward + built on your example. If you know that the post id is "254" you can skip all the other hoop-la.  That ID is unique in the WP system. The other filters help guarantee that the post is of "product' quality. Two words of caution in the use : 1-in the loop or around other queries this can get wonky (reset filters/query needed) and 2-I recommend adding a filter for "published" so you don't get drafts/etc leaking in. Glld luck.

Answer (score 0):

Add `'orderby'=> 'id'` to your wp query post and it will work fine, good luck.

Comment: But is `ID` really a valid index? wouldn't it be `p` or `page_id`?

Comment: So you mean `$args = array(
'post_type' => 'product',
'posts_per_page' => 100,
'orderby'=> 254
);` .... Would this return the data for the product with post id 254?

Comment: i think you can use post_id='wanted_post_id' in query post will work fine

Comment: @MostafaKasem I tried ` $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 200, 'post_id' => $id );`, but it didn't work still. I think its just returning all the products.

Comment: $my_query = query_posts('post_id=id&post_type=product');
    global $post;
    foreach ($my_query as $post) {
       // your display code
    }